# Substitute string using regex

Tags: r, string

I would like to substitue all of the segments with format `kr^s` (such as `k23^3`) using `k(23*3)` in a string.

For example, translate the string `"abk123^23*ck2^4"` into `"abk(123*23)*ck(2*4)"`.

How to achieve this operation in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string <- "abk123^23*ck2^4"
stringr::str_replace_all( string, "k([0-9]+)(\\^)([0-9]+)", "k\\(\\1*\\3\\)" ))
#[1] "abk(123*23)*ck(2*4)"
```

Comment: for simple uses, isn't `gsub` better? It's like 1/4 the charactres you had to type above and has a bunch of regex options more easily available?

Comment: @Sirius I think that depends on the usecase. Feel free to provide a `gsub()`-inspired answer.

Comment: Yep. Motivated by the usage you provided, `gsub` is also available: `gsub('k([[:digit:]]+)\\^([[:digit:]]+)', 'k\\(\\1*\\2\\)', x)`.

Comment: gsub would be an in-place replacement of the answer above, just swap the arguments around, `gsub(  pattern, replacement, x )`